# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFullWidth' of undefined with TSLint and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, gulp, tslint

I have been following the tutorials from Dan Wahlin and the online examples to configure Gulp and Typescript.  I have the code running, but I am unable to get tslint() to work.  The tslint() call always throws an exception:

```
node_modules\tslint\lib\language\walker\ruleWalker.js:18
    this.limit = this.sourceFile.getFullWidth();
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFullWidth' of undefined
at EnableDisableRulesWalker.RuleWalker [as constructor] (C:\Users\sscott\Development\OntarioDarts.com\node_modules\tslint\lib\language\walker\ruleWalker.js:18:37)
at EnableDisableRulesWalker.SkippableTokenAwareRuleWalker [as constructor] (C:\Users\sscott\Development\OntarioDarts.com\node_modules\tslint\lib\language\walker\skippableTokenAwareRuleWalker.js:11:16)
at new EnableDisableRulesWalker (C:\Users\sscott\Development\OntarioDarts.com\node_modules\tslint\lib\enableDisableRules.js:13:16)
at Linter.lint (C:\Users\sscott\Development\OntarioDarts.com\node_modules\tslint\lib\tslint.js:16:27)
at C:\Users\sscott\Development\OntarioDarts.com\node_modules\gulp-tslint\index.js:96:34
at respond (C:\Users\sscott\Development\OntarioDarts.com\node_modules\rcloader\index.js:73:7)
at respond (C:\Users\sscott\Development\OntarioDarts.com\node_modules\rcfinder\index.js:140:7)
at next (C:\Users\sscott\Development\OntarioDarts.com\node_modules\rcfinder\index.js:164:16)
at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:433:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:362:13)
```

I am using Windows 10.  I have typescript, tslint, gulp-typescript and gulp-tslint.

Installed Versions:

```
├─┬ gulp-typescript@2.10.0
│ └── typescript@1.7.3
├─┬ gulp-uglify@1.5.1
│ └─┬ uglify-js@2.6.0
│   └─┬ yargs@3.10.0
│     └─┬ cliui@2.1.0
│       └── wordwrap@0.0.2
├─┬ tslint@3.2.1
│ └─┬ optimist@0.6.1
│   └── wordwrap@0.0.3
└── typescript@1.7.5
```

Gulp task:

```
module.exports = function (gulp, PlugIns, Settings) {
    return function () {
        gulp.src([Settings.SourceFiles.TypeScript])
            .pipe(PlugIns.plumber())
            .pipe(PlugIns.debug())
            .pipe(PlugIns.typescript())

            .pipe(PlugIns.tslint( {
                configuration: {
                    rules: {
                        "class-name": true,
                        "comment-format": [
                            true,
                            "check-space",
                            "check-uppercase"
                        ],
                        "curly": true,
                        "eofline": true,
                        "indent": [
                            true,
                            "tabs"
                        ],
                        "jsdoc-format": true,
                        "max-line-length": 100,
                        "no-unreachable": true,
                        "no-unused-expression": true,
                        "no-unused-variable": true,
                        "no-use-before-declare": true,

                        "one-line": [
                            true,
                            "check-open-brace",
                            "check-catch",
                            "check-else",
                            "check-whitespace"
                        ],
                        "quotemark": [
                            true,
                            "single",
                            "avoid-escape"
                        ],
                        "semicolon": true,
                        "switch-default": true,

                        "variable-name": [
                            true,
                            "allow-trailing-underscore",
                            "ban-keywords"
                        ],
                        "whitespace": [
                            true,
                            "check-branch",
                            "check-decl",
                            "check-operator",
                            "check-separator",
                            "check-type"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }))
            .pipe(PlugIns.tslint.report("stylish"))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(Settings.Destination.TSCompiled))
        ;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error often occurs if TSLint is told to process a file that doesn't end in a `.ts` or a `.tsx` extension. I would make sure that you aren't accidentally sending any `.js` files or files with other extensions. It's possible in the future that `.js` files work correctly, but right now they won't.

In addition, I would try running TSLint from the command line with the same configuration on a few of your files. If it's not working correctly like this, it could indicate a TSLint bug.

Comment: I changed my file to try to only process one file, which failed the same way on a .ts and a .tsx.  However, tslint does work from the command line as you suggested.  I have logged a bug with gulp-tslint.  https://github.com/panuhorsmalahti/gulp-tslint/issues/52

Comment: As I cannot edit my last comment now due to age, the issue with gulp-tslint has been corrected and works with the newer versions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! When using `tslint src/ts/Person.ts` linting worked for me. :)